# RegExp is not matching on space and text after the pattern

Tags: regex

I have a multi-line pattern whereby I am scanning a string. The objective is to match on a sequence of numbers that make up an account number. Should the string/line start with a http|https, the pattern can ignore the line.  I am ignoring the case sensitivity throughout the pattern.  I am creating a boundary around the numeric only.  The numeric number can range from 12 digits to 19 digits in length.

Here is the regex:

```
(?mi)^(?!https?:).*(\b(50[0-9]{10,17}))$
```

Example tests:

- 501234567890
- Hi Bob, Here is what you asked for: 501234567890.  Did you get it?
- Hi Steven, Here is what you ask for 501234567890 Did you get it?
- http:///www.example.com/appid=501234567890 (?#  This should be ignored)
- https://www.example.com/appid=501234567890 (?#  This should be ignored)
- This is my company account number: 501234567890
- 501234567890

Line two and three are not matching. Line six is matching because there is NO space after the numeric numbers.   Line seven is not matching because there is a space before the numeric digits.

I have tried [^a-zA-Z\s] before and after numeric pattern, but is not working.

Suggestions and recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Russ

Comment: Do you need the `$` at the end of the regex pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `$` by a word boundary `\b`:

```
(?mi)^(?!https?:).*(\b(50[0-9]{10,17}))\b
```

Comment: you are correct.   I tested the change and it is exactly what I needed.  Can you explain why \b correct?  I have several patterns like this and I need to understand the theory behind such change.  The \b before the pattern means match the whole "word" only.  Does the word boundary require an denotation like a behind and end?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @rray: A word boundary `\b` Is a zero-length assertion that matches a "boundary" between a word character `\w` ( or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and a non word character `\W` ( or `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`). See more info here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html